# Automatically setting the limits of an axis when the other is manually defined in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

Consider the following example:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) +
  geom_point() +
  coord_cartesian(c(15, 20))
```

It sets the the limits of the x-axis, but the y limits remain as with the original plot, leaving a huge empty area.

Is it possible to automatically adjust y limits in this case? Similar to what

```
ggplot(mtcars[mtcars$mpg>15&mtcars$mpg<20,], aes(mpg, wt)) +
  geom_point()
```

would produce.

Such automatism would make it unnecessary to manually calculate the y limits (which is not even trivial unless `expand=0`, as one has to take into account how y limits are expanded compared to what is provided).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just set the y limits too?

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) +
  geom_point() +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(15, 20), ylim = c(2.5,4.5))
```

Of course you can calculate the limits beforehand with some function, but I'm not sure if that makes any sense, because to calculate the limits in a region, you will have to tell that function which are the limits of the region, which represents the same amount manual effort as putting those limits into the ggplot function directly.

Such a function could look like this:

```
find_ylimits <- function(data,xlim,overhead = 1){
  filter <- xlim[1] <= data[[1]] & data[[1]] <= xlim[2]
  c(min(data[[2]][filter])*overhead,
    max(data[[2]][filter])*overhead)
}
```

And then you could make the plot as follows:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) +
  geom_point() +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(15, 20), ylim = find_ylimits(mtcars[,c("mpg","wt")],c(15,20)))
```

Comment: The question is specifically if I can avoid manual calculation. It would be nice for two reasons, first, it'd be easier, second, and more important, it'd be more elegant if I could reproduce what `ggplot` would do if the data was indeed subsampled, see my second code chunk. Matching those limits (i.e., getting a consistent behavior of subsampling and "zooming"!) seems to be non-trivial due to `expand`. (At least I don't even know how default expansion works exactly, and even if I'd know, it'd further complicate the calculations.)

Comment: By consistency I meant that I aim to get the exact same y limits with `coord_cartesian(xlim = c(15, 20))` that I would _automatically_ get for the y axis with the `mtcars[mtcars$mpg>15&mtcars$mpg<20,]` data.

Comment: I've added an example function I can think of. I still think there is

Comment: What about using `+ scale_y_continuous(expand=expansion(add = -1))` instead? I'm not sure if using `add = -1` in the `expansion()` works for all situations though. It works with this situation. You may also want to fiddle with the number to get the exact desired y-axis range.

Comment: Well, yes, but the manual fiddling is what I specifically tried to avoid... But it seems that it is simply not possible.