How to zoom in on a ggplot by specifying only one axis?
Suppose I have some data that looks like this:
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(x = c(0, 2, 5),
             y = c(1000, 1, 1))

df |> 
    ggplot(aes(x,y)) + 
    geom_line()


I want to zoom in on a region based on the x value.  But when I try to use coord_cartesian like this
df |> 
    ggplot(aes(x,y)) + 
    geom_line() +
    coord_cartesian(xlim = c(1.5, NA))

the y axis does not automatically adjust.  It gives a lot of empty space like this

If I filter the data before plotting, then I'll lose the meaningful diagonal segment.  This image needs to be automatically generated, so I cannot manually specify the ylim in coord_cartesian.

If the plot will be automatically generated, presumably the "zoom" on the x-axis is also automatic.  How is the zoom determined?

In my application, the x-axis is a date and I take the most recent 6 months.  The spacing of the data points are quite variable and unpredictable.

Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/67664661/680068 Looks like we have to do some pre-calculation.

I'm not aware of any way of doing this without some pre-calculation, but here's one way of doing it that works reasonably well with your test data.  The approach I take is to determine the y values for the lowest x value you want in the plot and the highest x value that you don't.  Then calculate a "nice point" somewhere between the two and use that as the limit for the y axis.
If your real data are not monotonic, you will probably need to be more sophisticated with both your selection of the upper and lower guesses for the y limit, and the method of choosing a "good" intermediate value.
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(x = c(0, 2, 5),
             y = c(1000, 1, 1))

df |> 
  ggplot(aes(x,y)) + 
  geom_line()

zoomPlot <- function(d, xLower, fudge = 0.5) {
  yUpper <- d %>% filter(x < xLower) %>% head(1) %>% pull(y)
  yLower <- d %>% filter(x >= xLower) %>% head(1) %>% pull(y)
  yUpper <- round(yLower + (yUpper - yLower) * fudge, 0)
  d |> 
    ggplot(aes(x,y)) + 
    geom_line() +
    coord_cartesian(xlim = c(xLower, NA), ylim = c(NA, yUpper))
}

df %>% zoomPlot(1.5)

giving

